# twig testing global value in template

Tags: symfony, twig

In my symfony project, I have a config variable in my parameters.yml

```
role : front1
```

In my config.yml, my config variable is exposed

```
twig:
   globals:     
      role : %role%
```

In my template.html.twig, when i try to test it with an if, I have an error.

```
{% if {{role}} == 'front2' %}
    {# front2 #}
    (2)
{% else %}
    {# front1 #}
    (1)
{% endif %}
```

The error:
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in ::base.html.twig at line 132

I don't understand where is the mistake. 
Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try {% if role == 'front2' %}

Comment: Thank you, it works. Sorry for the waste of your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, as Oligan said:

```
{% if {{role}} == 'front2' %}
```

Is wrong. You need to use:

```
{% if role == 'front2' %}
```

Only use {{variable}} outside conditions.